# SQL Server Crosstab/Pivot query that includes groups by id and gets row based on highest value in column

Tags: sql-server, group-by, pivot, crosstab

I have:

Name of the table is "myTable" and maximum number value is 7.

| index | id | number | letter | date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 999 | 1 | a | 1/1/99 |
| 1 | 999 | 2 | a | 1/2/99 |
| 2 | 999 | 3 | a | 1/3/99 |
| 3 | 999 | 3 | b | 1/4/99 |
| 4 | 999 | 4 | a | 1/5/99 |
| 5 | 999 | 4 | b | 1/6/99 |
| 6 | 999 | 5 | a | 1/7/99 |
| 7 | 888 | 1 | a | 2/1/99 |
| 8 | 888 | 1 | b | 2/2/99 |
| 9 | 888 | 1 | c | 2/3/99 |
| 10 | 888 | 2 | a | 2/4/99 |
| 11 | 888 | 2 | b | 2/5/99 |
| 12 | 888 | 3 | a | 2/6/99 |
| 13 | 888 | 4 | a | 2/7/99 |

I'd like:

| index | id | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 | 7 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 999 | 1/1/99 | 1/2/99 | 1/4/99 | 1/6/99 | 1/7/99 |  |  |
| 1 | 888 | 2/3/99 | 2/5/99 | 2/6/99 | 2/7/99 |  |  |  |

So rows with the highest letter for the same number are included in the output, and null values are empty strings or null.

The number value can be 1 through n, and the letters a through zzz.  And there are way more than the one example id I have in there.

EDIT: I'm also given the maximum value for the number column and I've updated the illustration to show this.

Been at this for three days and tried many different approaches, any help is greatly appreciated.

SOLUTION: I was able to solve this problem by creating a stored procedure that I could pass some variables that would run a loop to create the query. One of the variables that get passed to the stored procedure is an integer that tells me how many columns I need to create, and then I build a pretty complex query using Pivots and Joins to get the output I need.

I'll post more details on this solution as soon as I wrap up the project and have a moment to generalize everything.

Comment: Don't reduce your sample data to a point that it does not fully illustrate your issue. Try adding some rows with a different ID and also remove some rows for id = 999. You seem to have ignored all the other index values - why? It seems you need a dynamic pivot but your logic / goal is not clear. If you can do this, think about how the resultset will be consumed. Whatever does that will need to handle any number of columns.

Comment: @SMor I think the illustration has everything needed to answer the question -- anything else I add would be adding clutter and also be redundant.  The indexed data from table 1 is all in table 2, I'm not ignoring them, that's just the result of a crosstab query.

Comment: @SMor An additional variable has been provided to me that opened up the need for additional context in the illustrated tables.  I don't think I'm leaving any necessary details out again, though.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work just fine...?

```
Create Table #T([Index] Int, ID Int, Number Int, Letter Varchar(10), [Date] DateTime)

Insert Into #T([Index], ID, Number, Letter, [Date])
Values
(0  ,999    ,1  , 'a',  '1/1/99'),
(1  ,999    ,2  , 'a',  '1/2/99'),
(2  ,999    ,3  , 'a',  '1/3/99'),
(3  ,999    ,3  , 'b',  '1/4/99'),
(4  ,999    ,4  , 'a',  '1/5/99'),
(5  ,999    ,4  , 'b',  '1/6/99'),
(6  ,999    ,5  , 'a',  '1/7/99'),
(7  ,888    ,1  , 'a',  '2/1/99'),
(8  ,888    ,1  , 'b',  '2/2/99'),
(9  ,888    ,1  , 'c',  '2/3/99'),
(10 ,888    ,2  , 'a',  '2/4/99'),
(11 ,888    ,2  , 'b',  '2/5/99'),
(12 ,888    ,3  , 'a',  '2/6/99'),
(13 ,888    ,4  , 'a',  '2/7/99')

Select 
  [Index] = Row_Number() Over (Order By ID) - 1,
  ID, [1], [2], [3], [4], [5], [6], [7]
From
(
  Select
    ID, Number = T.Number, [Date]
  From 
    #T As T
  Where
    [Index] = (Select Top (1) HighestLetter.[Index]
            From #T As HighestLetter
            Where HighestLetter.ID = T.ID
              And HighestLetter.Number = T.Number
            Order By HighestLetter.Letter Desc)
) As Highest
Pivot
(
  Max([Date])
  For Number In ([1], [2], [3], [4], [5], [6], [7])
) As Piv
```

Comment: Thank you, @Stu, the solution I ended up with is inline with your example here.  I appreciate you taking the time to respond :)